# How do I clear individual types of browser data in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

Prior to upgrading my MacBook Pro to OS X Yosemite, I was able to clear individual types of browser data (such as cookies, visited URLs and website data) in Safari. However, the  "Clear History and Website Data..." option in the new version of Safari only lets me choose how far back I want to clean the data; it doesn't let me choose what types of data to clear. How do I enable the option for choosing the data types?

I'm sure the solution is very simple, but I can't seem to figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 1):

For cookies: The option to delete all of your cookies stored on your hard drive lies under your under the “Privacy” tab. There, click on “Remove All Website Data…” then click “Remove Now.” To delete individual cookies, click “Details…” under the “Privacy.” From there, find the specific cookie and delete it accordingly.